# Why does my raspberry pi hang when reading from serial from arduino if sent by `serial.write` but not by `serial.print`?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

pi and arduino newbie here. I'm trying to send a signal from an arduino that triggers and receives a pulse from an ultrasonic sensor (hc-sr04), and sends the time of pulse duration to a raspberry pi. I can read the value fine on the raspberry pi if I use `Serial.println()` on the arduino, but not if I use `Serial.write()`: in this case, my code on the pi hangs when trying to read. I've looked at the arduino doc and know the difference between `write()` (binary data) and `print()` (human-readable), but still don't know why the hang is taking place.

Relevant python code on the pi:

```
import time, serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=10)
while True:
    val = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print(f"{val})
```

Relevant arduino code:

```
pulse_dur = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH);
Serial.println(pulse_dur);  // works fine
Serial.write(pulse_dur);    // causes hang
```

Comment: The differences between `Serial.print()` and `Serial.write()` is that `Serial.print()` send data as ASCII while 'Serial.print()` send data as byte. So if you do Serial.print(3.14), it will be sent as ASCII '3', '.', '1', '4', each as a char represented by its ASCII.

Comment: Thanks yeah as I said in my question I'm aware of that, but still not sure why the python `serial.Serial.readline()` function is hanging, as I mention with my example code

Comment: See the [documentation](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline) for the explanation of `Serial.readline()` function, it is not hang, it is expecting you to send a `\n` to terminate the line when you using `Serial.write()`.

Comment: ah I see, thank you!